# How to pass an int to controller using $.ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, model-view-controller

I'm trying to pass an int via ajax to my controller. My ajax syntax is this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'testAjax.htm',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(groupId),
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

And here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/testAjax.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String testAjax(@RequestBody String info) {
        System.out.println(info);
        return info;
    }
```

Before the data I'm wanting to pass is passed to the controller, the variable I'm working with is just a number (1, 3, 5, etc.), but when I pass it to the controller, it's converted to the number in question but then adds '=' to the end of it. So for the success part of the ajax call, if I pass '1', it alerts '1='. What am I doing wrong and how can I pass just an int? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to send a key/value pair. `data: JSON.stringify({ info: groupId })`. Also note that the Java is expecting a string value, not an integer. May be an issue, depending on how strict your model binder is.

Comment: Tried that and that info is now showing as this: "%7B%22info%22%3A1%7D=". I'm guessing I need to parse it somehow on the server side, but am unsure how I might do that.

Comment: Given that output it sounds like you don't need to stringify the values. Try just `data: { info: groupId }`

Comment: Alright, with that I've got it showing up on the server as "info=1". Which is fine, I can work with that. But do you know if there's a way to pass just the value into the variable I have on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Create data object and pass it to JSON.stringify function.

```
var obj = {'intParams': 8}
$.ajax({
      url: 'testAjax.htm',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(obj),
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
});
```